# Existence of minimizers

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization

I came accros this two exercises on existence of minimizers:

(Pointwise gradient constraint) It is exercise 15 in chapter 8 in Evans PDE book

(a) Show there exists a unique minimizer $u \in A$ of

$I[w]=\int_{\Omega}(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2-fw) dx$

where $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $A=\{u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega), |\nabla u|\leq 1$ a.e. in $\Omega\}$.

(b) Prove
$\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla(w-u)dx\geq \int_\Omega f(w-u)dx$
for any $w\in A$

This is second exercise:

Let $U_0 \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and let $u_0$ be the trace of $U_0$ on $\partial \Omega$, where $\Omega \in C^{0,1}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $A=\{u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega), u=u_0$ on $\partial \Omega \}$. Let $a_{ij} \in L^\infty (\Omega),i,j=1,2,\dots,d $ ,fulfill the ellipticity condition. Let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. Show that there exists a unique minimizer of

$I[w]=\int_{\Omega}(\sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{ij} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_i}-fw) dx$

in $A$. Deduce the corresponding Euler Lagrange equation and show that the minimizer is the unique solution to this equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your willing to help. I didn't make much progress in the evans exercise, it looks like I should somehow edit the proofs from section 8.4.2 on page 492 but I haven't figured how yet.

But to the second exercise I have:
If I understand it correctly I should show that I is coercive, L is convex in first variable and we know that A is nonempty. If I prove this I should have existence. Convexity looks obvious to me from ellipticity so only thing to show is coercivity:

Comment: $\int_{\Omega}(\sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{ij} \frac{\partial w}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x_i}-fw) dx \geq \alpha ||\nabla w||_2^2 - \int f w dx \geq \alpha ||\nabla w||_2^2 - ||f||_2 ||w||_2 $ and this should be it because f is from $L^2$ and w is from sobolev. But I am not sure if I can use the theorem 3 for unicity from evans because there is assumption that integrand doesn't depend on w but if I understand it correctly our integrand is dependent on w.

Comment: Conserning the first exercise. The only difference with the problem in section 8.4.2 is the set A. But if I look at proofs of theorems 3 and 4 I only need that A is convex and it should be and that if $\nabla u_{k_j} \leq 1$ then $\nabla u \leq 1$ and this also should hold. Is there any other problem or usage of set A which I am missing?